# Drupal 7 import page programmatically

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to create script for auto data import from one drupal site to other.
I have site foo.com and bar.com I'm trying to import everything from bar.com into foo.com.

So far I've managed to write script that imports all content types, nodes, blocks, etc. All that left is to import page with content. CTools module has clear function to export page data (panels, varants and etc...) but i cant find import function. (in admin panel there is way to import exported page, but import goes through a lot of functions, its too difficult to track all the way)

Is there an easer way to import page programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import anything from one site to another you are doing a **site synchronization**. And the best tool for this is Drush and commands rsync and sql-sync. See at [Using Drush to synchronize and deploy sites](https://drupal.org/node/670460).

If you want to import only Panel Pages you may use the [Panel Import](https://drupal.org/project/panels_import) and of course [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features).

An alternative option is [Demo](https://drupal.org/project/demo) module to create site snapshots. Then a custom module can be used with a button to enable a demo snapshot.

And a more alternative idea is to create some feature modules (that add content, views, panels etc) and then a simple module that will have all these modules as required.

Comment: My task is to create single php file, that the client can run this file and all content types, panels, nodes etc will be created in his website.

Comment: Features module does this but not with a single php file.